# python print error after custom add method

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a Timecode calculator using python but I don't get why the output is wrong:

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, image=0):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.second = second
        self.image = image

    def __str__(self):
        return "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(self.hour, self.minute, self.second, self.image)

    def __add__(self, second_time):
        new_time = Time()
        #define image add for 24 FPS
        if(self.image + second_time.image) >= 24:
            self.second += 1
            new_time.image = (self.image + second_time.image) - 24
        else:
            new_time.image = self.image + second_time.image
        #define second add for 24 FPS
        if(self.second + second_time.second) >= 60:
            self.minute += 1
            new_time.second = (self.second + second_time.second) - 60
        else:
            new_time.second = self.second + second_time.second
        #define minutes add for 24 FPS
        if(self.minute + second_time.minute) >= 60:
            self.hour += 1
            new_time.minute = (self.minute + second_time.minute) - 60
        else:
            new_time.minute = self.minute + second_time.minute
        #define hours add for 24 FPS
        if(self.hour + second_time.hour) >= 24:
            new_time.hour = (self.hour + second_time.hour) - 24
        else:
            new_time.hour = self.hour + second_time.hour

        return new_time

time1 = Time(2, 23, 21, 10)

time2 = Time(2, 21, 2, 22)

test = time1 + time2

print(time1)
```

if I print time1 before "test = time1 + time2" time1 = 02:23:21:10 but when I print it after test like in the code above the value of time 1 is 02:23:22:10...

did I miss something? why would the value of time1 change?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're modifying `self.hour`, `self.minute` etc in your add method

Comment: Oh thanks that was fast!